# dynamic select data from database as filtering query php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, forms

the problem is solved my problem was I type down my dynamic select out of form and just echo it and when i call it just first option value was send to my code i change my code and works fine if you like you can use my code it's good if you want to have select data category for showing and filter list by dynamic input selection my code is working fine .

dynamic selection form database:

```
<?php
    $select_status_2 = "<select name='status1'>\n";
    $select_status_2 .= "<option value=''>ALL</option>\n";
    $dataset_2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM products ORDER BY subcategory ASC");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($dataset_2)) {
  $select_status_2 .= "<option value='".$row['subcategory']."'";
  if (strtolower($row['subcategory']) == strtolower($select_status_2)) {
    $select_status_2 .= " selected='selected'>".$row['subcategory']."</option>\n";
  } else {
    $select_status_2 .= ">".$row['subcategory']."</option>\n";
  }
} 
    $select_status_2 .= "</select>\n";
?>
```

this part is for show my dynamic select and submit button:

```
   <form action="inventory.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="sortlist" id="myform" method="post">
        <table width="90%" align="center"  border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6"  style="text-align:center;">
          <tr>
              <td align="left"><?php echo $select_status?></td>
              <td align="left"><?php echo $select_status_2?></select></td>
              <td colspan="3" width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="button2" id="button3" value="مرتب سازی"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="7"><?php echo $dyn_table; ?></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

this part is for filtering my query

```
<?php
    $status= $_POST['status'];
    $status1= $_POST['status1'];
    if(!isset($_POST['state']))
    {
        $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
        }
    else{
    if($_POST['state']){
        $status= $_POST['status'];
        $status1= $_POST['status1'];
         if($status1=="ALL"||$status=="ALL")
         $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products");
          }
          else
          {
              if($status1=="ALL")
              $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category='status'");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: So the point is that your database options are not showing up in your dropdown?

Comment: No you are not asking a question. You're not even using sentences to structure what you want.